# after using dislocker to unlock a disk in Ubuntu, Windows Bitlocker no longer recognizes the drive

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, bitlocker

Basically described the problem in the title. I've tried using the command line manage-bde(?) for bitlocker in Windows, but it just hangs. When I plug the drive in, it says access denied.

This is on Windows 10.

Comment: So, I've just gone in the recovery console and manually turned off encryption on all my drives. I want to upgrade the encryption anyway. I'm not sure if it would of worked in the normal recovery console, (I'm using windows install media), but it does recognize the drive for sure using this method.